# AngularJS - Model not updating on selection of radio button generated by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am generating a bunch of radio buttons using ng-repeat, and then trying to update a model when one of them is selected. This doesn't appear to be working.

The same markup works just fine when the radio inputs are hardcoded as opposed to being generated by ng-repeat.

This works:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="lunch" value="chicken" name="lunch">
<input type="radio" ng-model="lunch" value="beef" name="lunch">
<input type="radio" ng-model="lunch" value="fish" name="lunch">  
{{lunch}}
```

This doesn't:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="lunch" ng-repeat="m in meat" value="m" name="lunch">    
{{lunch}}
```

See jsfiddle showing both here: http://jsfiddle.net/mark_up/A2qCS/1/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="DynamicCtrl">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.lunch" ng-repeat="m in meat"  
    ng-value="m" name="lunch">    
    {{lunch}}
</div>
```

Should do the trick.

As I understand it, `ng-repeat` creates its own `$scope`. so you need to refer to the `$parent $scope;` Yes, AngularJS is tricky. Also you need to change the `value` to `ng-value` too.

Comment: An alternative to using `$parent` is to use an object property in the controller:  `$scope.selection = {lunch: 'chicken'};`, then in the HTML: `<input type="radio" ng-model="selection.lunch" ng-repeat="m in meat" ng-value="m" name="lunch"> {{selection.lunch}}`

Comment: Thanks @MarkRajcok! It was putting the `$scope.selection = {lunch: 'chicken'};` in the controller that helped me. And I found to remove my `ng-checked="true"` from the html radio button as well, 'cause that setting in the controller will select the correct radio button automatically/programmatically.

Comment: @MarkRajcok , what is the rationale behind using object property to avoid using $parent ?

Comment: @AlokMishra, using `$parent` assumes a certain HTML structure (e.g., no intervening `ng-include` or other directives that might create a child scope).  With an object property, you don't need to worry that your code might break if you change your HTML.

Comment: Super helpful!!

Answer (score 4):

the above issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1100)

That happens because ng-repeat creates a new scope. Basically, each `<input>` is creating a selectedOption value on its own inner scope. To work around that, create a new container object for that value. For example, you could declare in your controller:

```
$scope.data = {selectedOption: x};
```

And then in your template, use `ng-model="data.selectedOption"`

in this way, ng-model gets updated .. :)

this is tricky

Answer (score 2):

Just need to replace value with ng-value