# AngularJS - radio button not updating model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

First steps in AngularJS. I'm facing a strange problem related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674899/angularjs-model-not-updating-on-selection-of-radio-button-generated-by-ng-repe), but the solution doesn't work to me, maybe I'm missing something (as I said, I'm a really n00b with angular).

I'm my HTML, I'm building some radio buttons like that:

```
<div ng-Controller="PageTwo" >
    <h3>General Information > Knowledge About </h3>
          <div>
        <b>User</b>
        <div>
            <div ng-repeat="option in userOptions">
                <input type="radio" name="userGroups" ng-model="$parent.userSelected" value="{{option.id}}" id="{{option.id}}">{{option.text}}
                        </div>          
            </div>
            Selected thing: {{userSelected}}

        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my related Controller:

```
uxctModule.controller ('PageTwo', function ($scope, ModelData){
    $scope.data = ModelData;
    $scope.userOptions = [{text:'Option 1', id:0}, {text:'Option 2', id:1}, {text:'Option 3',id:2},  {text:'Option 4', id:3}];;
    $scope.userSelected = ModelData.knowledgeAboutUser;
});
```

The model is the following object

```
uxctModule.factory ("ModelData", function () {
   var data = {
            // more code here
        knowledgeAboutUser : 3,

   }
   return data
});
```

Now, the problem is that I'm logging in the console the ModelData object, and I've noticed  that it's not updating when clicking the radio buttons.
I think the binding it's ok: I've tried to change the value in the Model, and the app selects the corresponding radio button.

Any help it's really appreciated, I'm stuck on this for hours

Comment: check my answer, i've put up a working example

Comment: I don't understand why you think that `ModelData` should be updated when you choose `userSelected` as model.

Comment: @zeroflagL I'm obviously missing something, I started studying angular yesterday and looks like I'm doing a mess :(

Comment: `ModelData` is a factory from which you are getting that `knowledgeAboutUser` value, why do you want to modify that, and whats the purpose of doing that

Comment: @Sr.Richie its a wrong way....

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan I've started studying Angular just yesterday, so probably I'm wrong :)  I need to have a unique model shared between all my controllers, and that was the idea behind my ModelData approach. Every controller should modify it, in order to update the values in other controllers.

Comment: @Sr.Richie one simple idea is use a $watch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the intermediate variable `$scope.userSelected`:

```
<div ng-repeat="option in userOptions">
    <input type="radio" name="userGroups" ng-model="data.knowledgeAboutUser" value="{{option.id}}" id="{{option.id}}">{{option.text}}         
</div>
Selected thing: {{data.knowledgeAboutUser}}
```

Comment: thx, it looks like it's working...Now the only issue I have is that it's assigning a String (for knowledgeAboutUser: "2"), instead of a int (knowledgeAboutUser: 2). How can I avoid it?

Comment: @Sr.Richie use `ng-value` instead of `value`

Comment: @zeroflagL if I use ng-value the result in ModelData is knowledgeAboutUser: undefined

Comment: @Sr.Richie without the curly braces: `ng-value="option.id"`

Answer (score 0):

It working fine

just change

`$scope.userSelected`

to

```
$scope.userSelected.selected
```

**[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/44/)**

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory ("ModelData", function () {
   var data = {
            // more code here
        knowledgeAboutUser : 2,

   }
   return data
});

app.controller("PageTwo", function ($scope, ModelData) {
    $scope.userSelected = {};
    $scope.userOptions = [{text:'Option 1', id:0}, {text:'Option 2', id:1}, {text:'Option 3',id:2},  {text:'Option 4', id:3}];;
    $scope.userSelected.selected = ModelData.knowledgeAboutUser;
});
```

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-Controller="PageTwo">
     <h3>General Information > Knowledge About </h3>

    <div> <b>User</b>

        <div>
            <div ng-repeat="option in userOptions">
                <input type="radio" name="userGroups" ng-model="userSelected.selected" value="{{option.id}}" id="{{option.id}}">{{option.text}}
             </div>
        </div>
            {{userSelected.selected}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is updating the model? Because I'm printing it and it's still displaying knowledgeAboutUser : 3, even after clicking the buttons

Comment: man thx for your support, but the model keeps not updating :(  How are you testing it? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @Sr.Richie when you click the radio button the value within `{{userSelected.selected}}`
 is getting updated right.....see the working demo

Comment: no man, it's updating the $scope.userSelected, but not the corresponding ModelData value. I don't know why

Comment: `ModelData` value?? you mean the `knowledgeAboutUser` inside the `ModelData`